# Trying to write u-boot to router flash "Connection closed by foreign host"

Tags: flash, jtag, bootloader, openocd

I am trying to write a .bin file to the flash memory of my router.
I am following the steps as outlined [here](http://www.alfredklomp.com/technology/experia-v8/) as I am using the exact same router and a raspberry pi as well.

However, although I am able to write u-boot.bin to the RAM, every time I try to write it to the flash, as instructed in the guide, my telnet outputs "Connection closed by foreign host"
Additionally my openOCD also gets disconnected/crashes

**My Telnet output:**

```
>  flash_file u-boot.bin 
> vrx200: flash_init 
> JTAG tap: vrx200.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x00001183 (mfg: 0x0c1 (V3 Semiconductor), part: 0x0001, ver: 0x0) 
> JTAG tap: vrx200.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x00000183 (mfg: 0x0c1 (V3 Semiconductor), part: 0x0000, ver: 0x0) 
> target halted in MIPS32 mode due to debug-request, pc: 0xbfc00000 
> VRX200: EBU init
> VRX200: EBU swap enable 
> Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**My OpenOCD output**

```
    vrx200: flash_init
Info : JTAG tap: vrx200.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x00001183 (mfg: 0x0c1 (V3 Semiconductor), part: 0x0001, ver: 0x0)
Info : JTAG tap: vrx200.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x00000183 (mfg: 0x0c1 (V3 Semiconductor), part: 0x0000, ver: 0x0)
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to debug-request, pc: 0xbfc00000
VRX200: EBU init
VRX200: EBU swap enable
Segmentation fault
```

**Expected Telnet Output:**

```
> flash_file u-boot.bin
vrx200: flash_init
JTAG tap: vrx200.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x00001183 (mfg: 0x0c1 (V3 Semiconductor), part: 0x0001, ver: 0x0)
JTAG tap: vrx200.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x00000183 (mfg: 0x0c1 (V3 Semiconductor), part: 0x0000, ver: 0x0)
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to debug-request, pc: 0xbfc00000
VRX200: EBU init
VRX200: EBU swap enable
Flash Manufacturer/Device: 0x00c2 0x22cb
flash 'cfi' found at 0xb0000000
auto erase enabled
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
fast_data (0x1e22008c) is within write area (0x1e22010c-0x1e22210c).
Change work-area-phys or load_image address!
Falling back to non-bulk write
vrx200.cpu1: target state: halted
target halted in MIPS32 mode due to target-not-halted, pc: 0x1e220088
wrote 262144 bytes from file u-boot.bin in 925.382263s (0.277 KiB/s)
VRX200: EBU swap disable
vrx200: flashing done
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

**Additional info:**
*I have a raspberry pi zero W connected to the router from the article, using JTAG as explained in the article. I have an ethernet cable connected to the WAN port of the router which is connected to my main Router to which my pc is also connected*

Comment: You need to figure out why openocd is segfaulting, that's not a target error though might be in a little used code path triggered by target behavior.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your answer! Would you have any advice on how I should go about figuring that out? Is this a fault in the openocd config? Or a fault in the uboot-bin? Where should I look, im not very faimiliar with these things.

Comment: It would appear to be a bug in the openocd software, though it may only occur in specific target behaviors.  Check the source for fixes already made, then build a version with debug symbols and run it under gdb or whatever your machines native debugger is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Alright thanks! I will look into that :)